# How to move files of "specific extension" ( from directories ) to a new location while maintaining full directory structure ?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have **following directory structure** :

```
/home/dir1/abc.jpg 
/home/dir1/abc.pdf
/home/dir1/dir2/abc.jpg 
/home/dir1/dir2/abc1.jpg 
/home/dir1/dir2/dir3/abc.jpg
```

and I want to **copy jpg files from them to a new folder which will have same directory structure**, for eg.:

```
/home/newdir1/abc.jpg 
/home/newdir1/dir2/abc.jpg 
/home/newdir1/dir2/abc1.jpg 
/home/newdir1/dir2/dir3/abc.jpg
```

**How to achieve it** using rsync or any other software ?

Please help, Many Thanks !!

Comment: You'll need to provide lots more detail for your question to be answerable. If your question is about how to *program* something to do this, then include the code you've tried to use, along with the results you got and exactly what you were expecting. If not, (for example you just need help with the command line options of a tool like rsync or scp) you might want to try http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: find . -name <specify file names> -exec mv "{}" <target dir> ";"

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of what you've included in your question, there are a couple of things you might try.

You've specified that you want to "move" files.  That means you either use the `mv` command, or use `rsync`'s `--remove-source-files` option.  For example:

```
mv /source1/* /source2/* /path/to/targetdir/
```

or

```
rsync -a /source1/ /source2/ /path/to/targetdir/
```

You've no doubt already read the part of `rsync`'s man page that explains the difference between source dirs with and without their trailing slash.  If not, read up, because it's important.

If your "thousands of source files [with] similar names" need to be matched from within your source directories, leaving some other files behind, you need to determine whether your "similar names" can be differentiated using *pathname expansion* or if you should use a regular expression.  If the former, then adding the pathname expansion to your sources with either `mv` or `rsync` should be sufficient.  If you need to use a regex, then `find` may be a better option:

```
find /source1/ /source2/ -regex ".*/file[A-F][0-9][0-9].txt" -exec mv "{}" /targetdir/ \;
```

If these don't solve the problem, then you'll need to supply more detail in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a little shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/dir1
JPEGS=`find . -name "*.jpg"`
tar cf - $JPEGS | (cd /home/newdir1 ; tar xf -)
```

This first gets the list of all your jpg files with their relative paths, then writes a tar file of them to a pipe into a subshell which changes to the new directory, and then extracts the tar from its stdin.